# Set Jquery Ajax Events

Tags: ajax, jquery

I want to have a function called for every ajaxComplete call regardless of the ajax call. I know I can set a default value using my spinner by saying ('#spinner').ajaxComplete(complete) however if I have an ajax request that implements it's own complete my default complete method is not called.

How can I make a central function get called when any ajax call has completed??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach your ajaxComplete to the document; the ajax event will bubble up:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings) {
    // Do whatever you need here.
});
```

Comment: I just found that on the jQuery site too. I'll try it out and see if it works.

Comment: This will only call it if the event is not being implemented in the ajax request. I need it to be called even if the ajax request implements it.

Answer (score 2):

Attach the ajaxComplete listener to the DOM. This allows us to monitor it for any

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(e,request, options){
  //attach our listener for ajaxComplete to the DOM.
  //whenever an ajax call is completed, the DOM will send this function
  customAjaxCompleteFunction();
});

var customAjaxCompleteFunction = function(){
  alert("Custom Function for Each ajax call on complete!");
}
```

Comment: Is this not pretty much the same thing as the above answer but with an extra step?

Comment: Yes. I posted this a few seconds after him. What can I say, timing is everything in life and writing the custom function cost me the answer !